# Split list into multiple columns

Tags: php

I have this data that i return with mysql and i add it into a list but it is very long.
I want to split data into several columns using php.I am stuck here i need some ideas.One thing i know that there is jquery splitter but i want to use php how can i do it.
Thanks in advance for your reply.
The data is names of users but each group of users belongs to different group.
If anyone need further explanation please ask me.
Here is a picture for clarification 
[image]

Comment: Please post an example of your data and how you would like to parse it. It can't be guessed just by your description.

Comment: If you want these columns in HTML, it should be **HTML code** example here, not picture. Do you happen to know what HTML code you want? If not - you'd better ask it under html tag first.

Comment: This data groups and users comes from database mysql.That is why i want to create it php style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `array_chunk()` function to achieve this.  It will allow you to split your array into x number of parts which you can then use to put into columns.

ie. `array_chunk($input_array, 2);`

This obviously assumes you are creating an array of data from your mysql recordset.

Answer (score 0):

What data do you have? PHP [explode()](http://php.net/explode) splits strings:

```
$input_string = 'stuff;that;should;be;split';
$delimiter = ';';
$array = explode($delimiter, $input_string);
```